# How can I display json data in a qtextbox

Tags: python, pyside

For example I have this json data which is read in from a file:

```
{"name": "Gilbert", "wins": [["straight", "7"], ["one pair", "10"]]}
```

How can I then display this in an edit text box with formatted indentations

```
{  
   "name":"Gilbert",
   "wins":[  
      [  
         "straight",
         "7"
      ],
      [  
         "one pair",
         "10"
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks andy, I was unable to format it on my tablet :)

Comment: qtextbox or qtextedit??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **json** library

```
import json

from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtGui import QTextEdit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    s = {"name": "Gilbert", "wins": [["straight", "7"], ["one pair", "10"]]}
    js = json.dumps(s, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    w = QTextEdit()
    w.setText(js)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) and putting the results into your text box.

A quick example (without pyside):

```
import json
s = """{"name": "Gilbert", "wins": [["straight", "7"], ["one pair", "10"]]}"""
print(json.dumps(j, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Results:

```
{
    "name": "Gilbert",
    "wins": [
        [
            "straight",
            "7"
        ],
        [
            "one pair",
            "10"
        ]
    ]
}
```

If, instead of `print`ing, the results of the `json.dumps()` you assign it to a variable:

```
p = json.dumps(j, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

You are now able to set the content of your text box to `p` using the `QTextEdit`'s [`setText()` slot](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTextEdit.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTextEdit.setText)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the precise format you specify, but `pprint.pformat` with an appropriate `width` value produces a nicely-formatted string, which you can then insert into the text box:

```
import pprint
s = pprint.pformat({"name": "Gilbert", "wins": [["straight", "7"], ["one pair", "10"]]},
                   width=25)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(s)
{'name': 'Gilbert',
 'wins': [['straight',
           '7'],
          ['one pair',
           '10']]}
```